# Rudin's discussion on cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cantor-set

After defining the Cantor set $P$, Rudin claims no segment of the form $$\Big(\frac{3k+1}{3^m},\frac{3k+2}{3^m}\Big)\tag{24}$$ where $k$ and $m$ are positive integers, has a point in common with $P.$ (it took me a while to verify this; I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99458/rudin-principles-page-42-cantor-set) argument and accepted despite wanting more!)

Then he claims : **since every segment $(\alpha,\beta)$ contains a segment of the form $(24)\dots$**

I wanted to verify this i.e $\Big(\frac{3k_o+1}{3^{m_o}},\frac{3k_o+2}{3^{m_o}}\Big) \subseteq (\alpha,\beta) \subseteq (0,1) $ for some positive integers $k_o$ and $m_o$.

Attempt: For the possibility of inclusion we would want the length of $\Big(\frac{3k+1}{3^m},\frac{3k+2}{3^m}\Big)$ which is $\frac{1}{3^m}$ to be less than the length of $(\alpha,\beta)$ which is $\beta -\alpha$. By the Archimedean property it is possible to find an $m_o(\in \mathbb{N}) > \log_3\frac{1}{\beta - \alpha}$ so that $\frac{1}{3^{m_o}}<\beta -\alpha.$

But I have trouble finding the right $k_o.$ It is possible again to choose $k_o$ by Archimedean property to have $\frac{3k_o+1}{3^{m_o}}> \alpha.$ But how do you ensure that $\frac{3k_o+2}{3^{m_o}}< \beta?$

Comment: choose the length of the interval to be $1/3$ the length of $(\alpha,\beta)$ then just choose the first $k$ for which $3k+1/3^m$ is greater than $\alpha$.

Comment: You should choose $m_o$ so that $\frac{1}{3^{m_o}}$, shouldn't you? 'Cause the length of that interval is $1/3^{m_o}$..  Does it help you to choose such $k_o$ ?

Comment: @rldias right! corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you observed the length of the interval $\big(\frac{3k+1}{3^m},\frac{3k+2}{3^m}\big)$ is $\frac{1}{3^m}$. Now given $\alpha<\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, let $m$ be sufficiently large so that $\frac{1}{3^m}<\frac{\beta-\alpha}{4}$. This choice of $m$ implies that $$\text{($\star$) }\beta-\frac{4}{3^m}>\alpha$$

From now on $m$ is fixed and we have to choose $k$ (which is going to be dependent on $m$). Since $\frac{3k+1}{3^m}\rightarrow\infty $ as $k\rightarrow\infty$ there exists $k$ for which $\frac{3k+1}{3^m}>\alpha$, let $k_0$ be the minimal $k$ satisfying this condition.

It is left to show that the interval $\big(\frac{3k_0+1}{3^m},\frac{3k_0+2}{3^m}\big)$ lies in $(\alpha,\beta)$. We already know that $\alpha<\frac{3k_0+1}{3^m}$ hence it left to show that $\frac{3k_0+2}{3^m}<\beta$.

Suppose not, then $\frac{3k_0+2}{3^m}\geq\beta$, hence $\frac{3k_0-2}{3^m}+\frac{4}{3^m}\geq \beta$ we conclude that $\frac{3k_0}{3^m}\geq\beta-\frac{4}{3^m}$ From ($\star$) we have that $\frac{3(k_0-1)+1}{3^m}>\alpha$ which is a contradiction to the minimality of $k_0$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you! Been looking for this for a while. Also we are ensured of a minimal $k_0$ due to well-ordering principle of natural numbers, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, every subset of the Natural numbers has a minimum.